# Backbone.js View Update on Drop w/ HTML5 Drag & Drop

Tags: html, backbone.js

Having a bit of trouble getting my view to update on a drop event. I'm pretty sure the problem is in the function handleDrop().  Re-rendering of the view has worked on normal model.set({}) tests in the browser.  So, I know that is not where the problem lies...

**The Backbone Router**

```
App.Routers.Dashboard = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes: {
    "": "index"     
},

initialize: function(options) {

    },

index: function() {

var preflist = new App.Models.PrefList({});

preflist.fetch({
    success: function() {
      var paneloneview = new App.Views.PanelOne({ model: preflist });
      $('#panelone').html(paneloneview.render().$el);
    }  
});

var sourceID;
var payloads = {
poolpricedraggable: "poolprice",
nonedraggable: "smp"
};

var element = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

function handleDragOver(event) {
if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
return false;
}
function handleDrop(event) {
    dropzone = this.id;
    if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    console.log("recevied the data: " + payloads[sourceID] + " in #" + dropzone);
    var attribute = preflist.get('panel_one');
    preflist.set({panel_one: attribute});
    preflist.save();
}  

element('panelone').addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);            
element('panelone').addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
```

**The PanelOne View**

```
App.Views.PanelOne = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function() {                
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.model.bind('change', this.render);
},

render: function(){
    var panelonesetting = this.model.get('panel_one');
    this.$el.html(JST['dashboard/' + panelonesetting]({}));
return this;
}

});
```

Kindest regards,
AC

Comment: what's the type/value of `panel_one` attribute?

Comment: Thanks guys.  I posted this late at night, at the end of a 15 hour coding session.  Obviously, I was out of my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I can see here is that you are trying to set the value of a model using the same value from itself - which basically gets ignored as you are replacing value with itself and change in the model doesn't get detected - thus the render method is not being called.

You might want to manually call the render or trigger change event on the model yourself using the `trigger` method on the model. (if there is anything else going on outside of the code you provided - cause with what I can see here nothing would change anyway?)

Have you forgot to use information from the dragged object to alter settings of the model?

Comment: Yes, you're correct Tom.  Thank you :)  I'll post the correct code below.

Answer (score 0):

The code in my question above was written really late at night.  Now, I've awakened to see Tom and Mu pointing out the embarrassing mistake I've made (This feels similar to a drunk dialing incident).  Nonetheless, here is the corrected bit of code, and all of this should be handy for anyone with a backbone app who wants to include some drag and drop functionality to set model attributes:

```
    function handleDrop(event) {
       //  This dropzone var isn't used for anything here but may be useful for others. So, I've left it in...
       dropzone = this.id;
       // This preventDefault is necessary to prevent actions some older browsers like to do on drop events
       if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
       //  This model attribute should be set to the payload listed above
   preflist.set({ panel_one: payloads[sourceID] });
   preflist.save();
        }
```